# I can't get working ROCm on my AMD Radeon HD 8730M

Tags: linux, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon

I want to use hashcat, but it requires ROCm installed, for properly work with GPU on Linux (Kubuntu 20.04). I did install it using official tutorial.

But it doesn't work properly:

```
sudo /opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo
ROCk module is loaded
Unable to open /dev/kfd read-write: Cannot allocate memory
yuriy is member of video group
hsa api call failure at: /src/rocminfo/rocminfo.cc:1142
Call returned HSA_STATUS_ERROR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES: The runtime failed to allocate the necessary resources. This error may also occur when the core runtime library needs to spawn threads or create internal OS-specific events.
```

I did check kfd:

```
sudo dmesg | grep kfd

[   15.377575] kfd kfd: amdgpu: OLAND  not supported in kfd
```

I found recommendation to add line to file in the /etc/udev/rules.d/: `KERNEL=="kfd", MODE="0660", GROUP="video", TAG+="uaccess"`, but it doesn't help.

I know that my GPU AMD Radeon HD 8730M has support for GCN, that is required by ROCm.

```
Architecture Codename: Sea Islands
Chip Variant: Oland
Codename: Tiran
CLRX Version: GCN 1.0
```

Haven't any idea why ROCm don't work with my GPU. It doesn't seemsed to me too outdated card.
My linux work through amdgpu driver

How to make ROCm work? What's the alternatives to make hashcat work with GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems your device is not supported to work with ROCm. See the documentation [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm#Hardware-and-Software-Support).

Answer (score 0):

Try KERNEL="kfd", MODE="0660", GROUP="video", TAG+="uaccess" (so delete one '=' of the '==' for kfd)